# Unable to build when Added new Activity in project having Hilt - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

In my project, using dagger-Hilt

just by adding a new activity, it shows an error

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
    [Hilt] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

but before adding a new activity, the whole project works fine

Activity  :->

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
    }
}
```

my build.gradle

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
 classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
```

Comment: Please checkout my answer and let me know whether its working fine or not. Also update app level build.gradle in your question. Need to see how you are importing hilt libraries.

Comment: here sir project [build.gradle](https://github.com/th3kumar/Snoozz-Sleeping-Buddy/blob/master/build.gradle)  ,  Module [build.gradle](https://github.com/th3kumar/Snoozz-Sleeping-Buddy/blob/master/app/build.gradle)  ,

Comment: hey @GowthamKK  here is my whole [project](https://github.com/th3kumar/Snoozz-Sleeping-Buddy) .

Comment: Could you please update splash activity code in your project. I couldnt find any

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue. The real problem is with versions,your kotlin version is not compatible with hilt plugin version and hilt library version. Here are the few changes you need to do.

In project build.gradle, update hilt plugin version to 2.42

```
    classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42")
```

In app build.gradle, update to latest versions like below.

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42")
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```

Hilt lifecycle module not required in latest hilt version.
You should remove the below line in build.gradle and remove all `androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject` imports in your project.Other wise it will throw error

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
```